# How to get table details by passing 2 column data in jpa

Tags: sql, spring, hibernate, jpa, hql

My table looks like this:

```
ysql> select * from client_parent_question;
----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
 id | is_deleted | sort_order | version | cid | pid  | qid  |
----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
  1 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |   16 |   33 |
  2 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |   10 |   34 |
  3 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    3 |   35 |
  4 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |   17 |   36 |
  5 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    1 |   37 |
  6 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |    1 |   38 |
  7 |            |          3 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    1 |
  8 |            |          4 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    2 |
  9 |            |          5 |       0 |   1 |    1 |    4 |
 10 |            |          6 |       0 |   1 |    1 |   14 |
 11 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |   18 |   39 |
 12 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |   18 |   40 |
 13 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |   12 |   25 |
 14 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |   12 |   26 |
 15 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    9 |   24 |
 16 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    5 |    7 |
 17 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |    2 |    1 |
 18 |            |          7 |       0 |   1 |    1 |   15 |
 19 |            |          8 |       0 |   1 |    1 |   44 |
 20 |            |          3 |       0 |   1 |    7 |   42 |
 21 |            |          1 |       0 |   1 |    4 |   32 |
 22 |            |          2 |       0 |   1 |    4 |   12 |
 23 |            |          1 |       0 |   2 |    1 |    1 |
 24 |            |          1 |       0 |   2 |    3 |   51 |
 25 |            |          2 |       0 |   2 |    1 |    6 |
----+------------+------------+---------+-----+------+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is `ClientParentQuestion` class:

```
@Configurable
@Entity
public class ClientParentQuestion {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Integer version;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Client cid;

    @ManyToOne
    private Parent pid;

    @ManyToOne
    private Question qid;

    private boolean isDeleted; 

    private int sortOrder;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    public Client getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    public void setCid(Client cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    public Parent getPid() {
        return pid;
    }

    public void setPid(Parent pid) {
        this.pid = pid;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public int getSortOrder() {
        return sortOrder;
    }

    public void setSortOrder(int sortOrder) {
        this.sortOrder = sortOrder;
    }

    public Question getQid() {
        return qid;
    }

    public void setQid(Question qid) {
        this.qid = qid;
    }


}
```

I know `pid` and `cid` and I want the all the details. So the SQL is

```
SELECT  cpq.qid FROM client_parent_question cpq  WHERE cpq.pid=1 AND cpq.cid=1;
```

But when I tried to implement in my JPA like this:

```
public List getAllSavedQuestions(Long pid,Client client)
{
    Long cid=client.getId();
    System.out.println(cid);
    System.out.println("client  "+client.toString());
    //String queryString="SELECT distinct q FROM Question q , ParentQuestion pq ,Parent p where pq.qid.id = q.id and  p.id = pq.pid.id and q.isDeleted=false  AND p.id = "+pid+" AND (q.cid.id="+cid+" or q.cid=null)";
    String queryString="select cpq from ClientParentQuestion where cpq.pid.id="+pid+" and cpq.cid.id="+cid;
    Query query=entityManagerUtil.getQuery(queryString);
    List questionsList =    query.getResultList();
    return questionsList;
}
```

Then i get the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [cpq.pid], unexpected token [cpq] [select cpq from com.iconma.surveytab.entity.ClientParentQuestion where cpq.pid.id=1 and cpq.cid.id=1]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [cpq.pid], unexpected token [cpq] [select cpq from com.iconma.surveytab.entity.ClientParentQuestion where cpq.pid.id=1 and cpq.cid.id=1]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:286)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.aspectj.JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.ajc$afterThrowing$org_springframework_orm_jpa_aspectj_JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect$1$18a1ac9(JpaExceptionTranslatorAspect.aj:15)
    at com.iconma.surveytab.dao.implementations.EntityManagerUtil.getQuery(EntityManagerUtil.java:75)
    at com.iconma.surveytab.dao.implementations.ServiceClientDaoImpl.getAllSavedQuestions(ServiceClientDaoImpl.java:291)
    at com.iconma.surveytab.service.implementations.ServiceClientServiceImpl.getAllSavedQuestions(ServiceClientServiceImpl.java:1015)
    at com.iconma.surveytab.controllers.ServiceClientController.getAllQuestions(ServiceClientController.java:543)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:426)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:790)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:719)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:644)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:549)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:368)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:109)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:35)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:177)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:187)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:380)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at com.springsource.insight.collection.tcserver.request.HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.invoke(HttpRequestOperationCollectionValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [cpq.pid], unexpected token [cpq] [select cpq from com.iconma.surveytab.entity.ClientParentQuestion where cpq.pid.id=1 and cpq.cid.id=1]
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1201)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:275)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy510.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy504.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: Unable to resolve path [cpq.pid], unexpected token [cpq] [select cpq from com.iconma.surveytab.entity.ClientParentQuestion where cpq.pid.id=1 and cpq.cid.id=1]
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolveAsNakedComponentPropertyRefLHS(IdentNode.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.IdentNode.resolve(IdentNode.java:108)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.tree.DotNode.resolveFirstChild(DotNode.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker.lookupProperty(HqlSqlWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4774)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExprLhs(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:5300)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.addrExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4759)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.expr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1326)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.exprOrSubquery(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:4471)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.comparisonExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3944)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:2047)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.logicalExpr(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:1972)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.whereClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:831)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:254)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:272)
    ... 77 more
```

Can anybody please tell me what could be the reason?

Comment: It will help the readability of your code if you rename the properties in your ClientParentQuestion class so that the name looks like the joined entity and not like the id. For example `cpq.pid.id` becomes `cpq.parent.id`.

Answer (score 2):

The exception is being thrown because your query string is invalid. Hibernate doesn't know what the value of cpq is. You can either use the Criteria API like this:

```
Criteria criteria = getCurrentSession().createCriteira(ClientParentQuestion.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("pid.id", pid);
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("cid.id", cid);
return criteria.uniqueResult();
```

or modify your query string to add the alias `cpq` after the root class name `ClientParentQuestion`

```
select cpq from ClientParentQuestion cpq 
    where cpq.pid.id="+pid+" and cpq.cid.id="+cid
```

and AFAIK use a [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) to map your result into a ClientParentQuestion object.

Comment: You do not need to specify the ResultTransformer for this. The default will be to transform them into ClientParentQuestion objects, based on the select clause.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your description

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "pid")
private Parent pid;
```